# Can't get collision detection or onclick to work in THREE.js

Tags: collision-detection, three.js

I've spent 2 days now trying to get this collision detection and click on object to work, with some luck but not close to perfect. I want to detect the camera's collision with objects as it moves around the scene (like if it were a shuttle and it would go boom if you ran into a planet or sphere). Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI, ShipControls are a clone of FlyControls (slightly modified). Example: http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/solar-system/index2.html

Comment: Do you have a working example we could analyse?

Comment: Sure, http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/solar-system/index2.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to have the mouse collide with or click on, it seems that you have some mouse functionality already?

Comment: Check out the edit, maybe that will help clear it up a little more. And see the comment on the answer below for more details... hope that helps, if not I'll try to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

`Ray` doesn't support `ParticleSystem`. Yet!

Comment: Sorry, not talking about particles, the spheres. I've updated the code I've been working on at that linked. I've removed the click and collision detection because I couldn't get it to work. If you don't mind taking a look at that code and let me know what I need to do to integrate collision detection and on click events for objects I'd really appreciate it... btw, loving the script!

Comment: I've looked at the current code and I can't find any instance of "Ray" nor "intersectObjects"... Do you mind doing an isolated example of the problem you're having? It'll be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Here's the code I'm working on: [link](http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/072012/solar-system.html)

I've got the click code there, but couldnt figure out the collision code. The click code works... kinda, but isnt always right. guessing i have something messed up which is breaking the click and the collision when i tried to add it.

Comment: I just found that the click works as expected when you're not moving, but when you are thats when it starts getting funky. Guessing I need to account for movement some how?

Comment: nvm, thought that was it but the onclick is still funky even when you're not moving