# Units of Three.JS, Calculating Rotation & Orbit Speeds

Tags: rotation, three.js, orbit

I'm trying to build a to scale model of the solar system. I wanted to see if someone could explain to me how the rotation speed works. Here's the important piece:

```
objects[index].rotation.y += calculateRotationSpeed(value.radius,value.revolution) * delta;
```

How does the rotation speed relate to actual time? So if you have a speed of 1, is that a movement of 1 px per millisecond? Or if you have a speed of 0.1, is that less that a px a second?

Basically I'm trying to calculate the correct rotation speed for the planets given their radius and amount of hours in a day. So if you were on earth, it would complete 1 rotation in 24 hours. Here's the function that I wrote that's doing the calculation now:

```
/* In a day */
function calculateRotationSpeed(radius,hrs,delta) {
    var cir = findCircumference(radius);
    if(delta) {
        var d = delta;
    } else {
        var d = 1;
    }
    var ms = hrs2ms(hrs) * d;
    var pxPerMS = km2px(cir) / ms;
    return pxPerMS;
}
```

I gave it a try and it still seems to be moving too fast. I also need something similar to calculate orbit speeds.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

#### Rotation and Units

Rotation in Three.JS is measured in *radians*. For those that are completely unfamiliar with radians (a small excerpt from an old paper of mine):

> Like the mathematical constant [**Pi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), a [**radian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (roughly 57.3 degrees) is derived from the relationship between a circle's radius (or diameter) and its circumference. One radian is *the* angle which will always span an arc on the circumference of a circle which is equal in length to the radius of that same circle (true for any circle, regardless of size). Similarly, Pi is the ratio of circumference over diameter, such that the circumference of the unit circle is precisely Pi. Radians and degrees are not actually *true* units, in fact angles are in general dimensionless (like percentages and fractions, we do not use actual units to describe them).
>
> However, unlike the degree, the radian was *not* defined arbitrarily, making it the more natural choice in most cases; often times being much easier and much more elegant, clear, and concise than using degrees in mathematical formulae. The Babylonians probably gave us the degree, dividing their circle into 6 equal sections (using the angle of an equilateral triangle). each of these 6 sections were probably further subdivided into 60 equal parts given their [**sexagesimal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) (base 60) number system. This would also allow them to use such a system for astronomy because the estimated number of days in a year was much less accurate during their time and was often considered 360.

#### Basic Rotation in Three.JS

So now, knowing you're working in radians, if you increment the rotation of an object by 1 you will be incrementing the rotation of the object by one radian. For example, consider making the following calls in the callback to `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
mesh.rotation.x += 1;                     // Rotates by  1 radian per frame
mesh.rotation.x += Math.PI / 180;         // Rotates by  1 degree per frame
mesh.rotation.x += 45 * Math.PI / 180     // Rotates by 45 degrees per frame
```

As the above examples show, we can easily convert a value in degrees into a value in radians by multiplying by a constant factor of `Math.PI / 180`.

#### Taking Framerate Into Account

In your case, you will also need to take into consideration how much time passes with each frame. This is your *delta*. Think about it like this: What framerate are we running at? We'll declare a global `clock` variable which will store a `THREE.Clock` object which has an interface to the information we require:

```js
clock = new THREE.Clock();
```

Then, in the callback to `requestAnimationFrame`, we can use `clock` to get two values that will be useful for our animation logic:

```js
time = clock.getElapsedTime(); // seconds since clock was instantiated 
delta = clock.getDelta();      // seconds since getDelta was last called
```

The `delta` value is meant to represent the time between each frame. However, note that this is only true when `clock.getDelta` is called consistently, exactly **once** in the same place somewhere within the callback to `requestAnimationFrame`. If `clock.getDelta` somehow gets called more than once or is called inconsistently it's going to screw things up.

#### Rotating With A Delta Factor

Now, if your scene doesn't bog down the processor or the GPU, then Three.JS and it's included `requestAnimationFrame` will try to keep things running at a smooth 60 frames per second. This means that ideally we will have approximately `1/60 = .016666` seconds between each frame. This is your `delta` value which can be obtained by calling `clock.getDelta` each frame.

We can use the `delta` value to decouple the rate at which we animate objects by multiplying as shown below. In this case, multiplying by `delta` will allow us to update our rotation at a rate defined in terms of seconds (as opposed to updating the rotation per frame as we did before). Multiplying by the `delta` value will also allow us to smoothly animate objects at a constant velocity without being effected by any small variations in the framerate from frame to frame and will even maintain that velocity even in the case that the framerate drops below the target 60fps (for example 30FPS, 45FPS, etc).

So, the examples we considered previously now become:

```js
mesh.rotation.x += delta * 1;                     // Rotates  1 radian per second
mesh.rotation.x += delta * Math.PI / 180;         // Rotates  1 degree per second
mesh.rotation.x += delta * 45 * Math.PI / 180;    // Rotates 45 degrees per second
```

#### Rotational Speed and Units

Because radians and degrees are not actually units defined in terms of distance/size), then when we we calculate our rotational speed (angular velocity) you'll see that it is going to be a function *only* of time and is not dependent on the radius as in your code.

#### Calculating Rotational Speeds Based On Time

For example, you don't need the radius of a planet to calculate its angular velocity, instead you can calculate it using only the number of hours in a day or the amount of time it takes for the planet to complete a single revolution (ie. the duration it takes for the planet to rotate `2 * PI` *radians* on it's axis).

If we assume that the Earth has exactly `24 hours = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86,400 seconds` in a day (it doesn't). Then, given that there are `2 * PI` radians in a complete revolution (360 deg), we can calculate the Earth's constant angular velocity in radians as:

```js
radsPerRevolution = 2 * Math.PI;
secsPerRevolution = 24 * 60 * 60;
angularVelocity = radsPerRevolution / secsPerRevolution ;  // 0.0000727 rad/sec
```

The above only needs to be calculated once, outside of the callback to `requestAnimationFrame`, as the value never changes. You could probably find textbook values that will be more accurate than this (taking into account a more accurate measurement than our 24 hour flat figure for the amount of time it takes for Earth to complete a revolution).

At this point, rotating our mesh with the same angular velocity as Earth would be as simple as updating its rotation every frame by incrementing its value by `delta` multiplied by the constant `angularVelocity`. If `angularVelocity` is defined as above, this can be done by calling the following in the callback to `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
mesh.rotation.x += delta * angularVelocity;
```

#### In Conclusion

I wouldn't worry about making sure you have all of the angular velocities for the planets exactly correct. Instead, a better idea might be to work out what the ratios between each of the angular velocities (of the planets) are and use those. This might work better since it will allow you to speed up or slow down the animation as desired, and as when working with any model (particularly astronomical models) the most important thing is that you keep it to scale, not necessarily, the scale doesn't necessarily have to be 1:1.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense. Never been any good at math, so with this how would I calculate the speed or radians per frame based off of the radius and amount of time is takes to complete 1 revolution?

Comment: See my edit, I added a lot of things. But like I say at the end, I wouldn't use the actual speeds of the planets based off of the number of hours in a day. Instead compare them to one another and just make sure the ratios between them stay the same. Also I would make everything static at first and just work on their individual rotations in relation before you try to make any orbits.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot and if you wanna take a stab at this one (see the comments) that would be awesome! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331663/cant-get-collision-detection-or-onclick-to-work-in-three-js)

Comment: "Note that delta is meant to return the amount of time between each frame; however, this will be true if and only if clock.getDelta is consistently called within anim/render" And i was wondering why `getDelta()` returns garbage in my case...too bad i need to learn from StackOverflow something that should be as a bold font in the official documentation.

Comment: This has to be one of the best answers I've ever seen on Stack Overflow